# Deploy Fleet server in self managed setup

Tags: elastic-stack, self-hosting, fleet

I am new and testing elastic stack self managed setup.

I already have installed elastic stack in Ubuntu.

I would now like this machine also to act as a fleet server ?
Is it possible ?
How would I set that up ?

Thanks

Comment: Which version are you using? Did you check the documentation?

Comment: Did check the documentation. [link]https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/master/add-a-fleet-server.html. It talks about setting it on a brand new machine but not on the same machine. If I try following the steps on the same machine, it says elastic-agent is already installed. Hence I was thinking that if I could somehow change the config. 

I am on version 8.1.2